# Is it possible to perform regression analysis and regression analysis (using PROCESS in SPSS)?

Tags: regression, spss, likert

I have a dependent variable and independent variable in 7-point Likert scale. And the mediator in 11-point Likert scale. Can I perform statistical analysis in SPSS in this case, and what should I do with 11-point Likert scale variable?

Comment: Welcome to cv, Alessandro! I was a bit puzzled about the title of your post (regression analysis and regression analysis) - guess you had something different in mind. Your problem seems to be different numer of categories in the variables on likert scale. It will mske other users more happy to answer if you shortly describe what you read about it (e.g. posts here) or tried :-)

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.